# How to commit files under Vendor which is not seen by Git

Tags: php, git, github, branch, commit

I have a project and there is a Vendor folder under my project and it is not seen by Git. To be clear any change is not detected by Git under Vendor file.
However, I want to commit some files to a branch. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `.gitignore`-file somewhere telling git to ignore the `/vendor`-folder? Change that file to fit your needs.

Comment: If you don't already have a `.gitignore` rules setup for this folder, you can just `git add` the files you want to add, and you're done.

Comment: Comment `/vendor` from `.gitignore` file which exists in root folder in most cases.

Comment: Why do you want to commit files in `vendor/`? Do you know how to install dependencies using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)? Its official recommendation is [not to commit the `vendor/` folder](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md).

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal thing to do with vendor files is to not add them in git, rather just make an entry in `composer.json` file.

If you want to edit those files according to your own need then, most of the packages can be published and the files will be available in your project directories for modifications.

Even if that doesn't helps you, the option is to remove the `./vendor` entry in `.gitignore` file.

And the most forceful way is to use `git add <filename>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to commit a folder in vendor directory .

You should find the package repository (*github* or *gitlab* , ...) and fork the package .

Then add and commit your changes to your fork .

After that you can use your fork repository address in your `composer.json` file and get your fork package like this :

```
"type": "project",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/sample/sampple.git"
    }
],
```

or you can also pull request to main repository and use the main repository.